# Удвоение определенного символа в строке

Tags: c, строки

**Помогите, пожалуйста, придумать, как удвоить символ в строке на языке Си.**

Задача формулируется так:

В стандартный поток ввода подается поочередно две строки. Первая содержит только букву латинского алфавита. 3атем подается строка, состоящая из слов, длиной не более 100 символов. Слова состоят из символов, отличных от пробела, слова разделены одним пробелом. Необходимо вывести в стандартный поток вывода строку, в которой в каждом слове будет продублирована каждая буква, написанная в первой строке входного потока.

> Ввод:
>
> o
>
> persona
>
> Вывод:
>
> persoona

Вот некоторые мои наработки:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char letter[2];
    gets(letter);
    char str1[150];
    gets(str1);
    char sym = letter[0]; //получил нужный символ из первой строки
    size_t length = strlen(str1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] = sym)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < length - i; j++)
            {
                str1[j + 2] = str1[j + 1];
            }
            str1[i + 1] = sym;
            
        }
    }
    printf("%s", str1);
}
```

Мой алгоритм не работает. Насколько я понял, функции по типу "replace" в языке Си нет. Помогите придумать другой алгоритм.

Comment: На вскидку примерно так, ```s,z string; z = 'test'; for (int i=0; i<strlen(z);i++) { if (z[i]=='e') s+=z[i]; s+=z[i];}``` PS. Это псевдокод, чтоб не кричали что тут куча ошибок, смысл алгоритма - понять можно, реализовать код за автора - не вижу смысла.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков кажется, вы не совсем поняли, что мне нужно в задании. мне нужно исходную строку переписать, просто удвоив некоторые буквы

Comment: Кто вам мешает сделать в конце скрипта вот так ```z=s;```;

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не работает

Comment: Что именно не работает? алгоритм или код который я привел? алгоритм - точно работает, а код - точно нет, и о том что это алгоритм а не готовое решение - сразу сказано :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков , из-за своей ошибки не работало, с алгоритмом все отлично, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удвоение символа `c` в строке `s` — только чтоб в ней было достаточно места для этих удвоенных символов — следите сами!

```
char * doubles(char * s, char c)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    for(const char * t = s; *t; ++t)
        if (*t == c) ++cnt;
    char *q = s + strlen(s) - 1,
         *t = s + strlen(s) + cnt;
    *t-- = 0;
    while(q >= s)
    {
        if (*q == c) *t-- = c;
        *t-- = *q--;
    }
    return s;
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/6FsjRe